# Virtualenv: TclError Can't find a usable init.tcl

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter, tcl, virtualenv

the issue: running Python's `matplotib` from a Windows virtual environment as reported & discussed [Github ticket 93](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/93) and a relevant suggested fix [here](https://github.com/jedie/DragonPy/commit/0c1add8ba246ac3fcd8287c3b30b387ca32bb2e3#diff-f11e22674d5a7f1c68650e7bdcea3a50R8).

Code (`myp.py`):

```
     import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
     import Tkinter as tk
     # insert code to read/load mydata
     pl.plot(mydata['foo'],mydata['bar'],'*')
```

Tcl Error:

```
 _tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
C:/Python27/lib/tcl8.5 C:/Users/Remi/MyVirtEnv/lib/tcl8.5....(ect)
```

Fix attempt 1: as suggested in ticket above, I added the following env. variables to path in batch file `activate.bat` located in `C:/Users/Remi/MyVirtEnv/Scripts/`:

```
set "TCL_LIBRARY=C:\Python27\tcl\tcl8.5"
set "TK_LIBRARY=C:\Python27\tcl\tk8.5"
```

Not resolved this way. Potentially relevant info: using `PyCharm` IDE with the following configuration:

```
Environment variables: PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
Python interpreter: python 2.7.10 virtualenv at C:\Users\Remi\MyVirtEnv
"buttons checked": Add content roots and Add source roots to PYTHONPATH
```

Any help I could get would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there an `init.tcl` in any of the directories it lists?

Comment: @ Donal: yep in `/Python27/tcl/tcl8.5`. Btw, the ugliest fix for now was to copy `/tk8.5` and `/tcl8.5` to `C:\Users\Remi\MyVirtEnv\Lib\`

Comment: @remi Did you find any elegant solution on this? I have same issue.

Comment: @ tomab: not really. The above fixed it for me and I did not look back.

Comment: The problem is that _something_ is causing `libtcl.dll` to not be able to locate the associated `init.tcl`. There's various reasons why that might happen, but most come down to people moving part of the installation around without moving the rest of it, or using the wrong value in the `TCL_LIBRARY` environment variable. I've a long-term fix for this — involving building a combined installation file — but that's still in alpha.

Answer (score 2):

After adding the following environment variables to path in batch file activate.bat located in the virtual environment, e.g.: C:/Users/Remi/MyVirtEnv/Scripts/:

```
set "TCL_LIBRARY=C:\Python27\tcl\tcl8.5"
set "TK_LIBRARY=C:\Python27\tcl\tk8.5"
```

it is able to launch IDLE in virtual environment.

Make sure the path is valid, e.g. "C:\Python27\tcl\tcl8.5"